# type of variable through indentation of loops Python

Tags: python, methods, types, indentation

Here is a snippet, in the code through the top- down way, I printed the type of the variable named "podium")
this is the code:

```
def frequence(entranche):
    podium = []
    print("premier podium", type(podium))
    for item in entranche:
        print ("deuxieme podium", type(podium))
        scat = len(entranche)
        for indice in range (len(entranche)):            
            if entranche[indice] == item:
                scat -= 1
            frequence = len(entranche) - scat

        podium = podium.append(frequence)
        print("troisieme podium", type(podium))
        plus_haute_frequence = max(podium)   
    return(plus_haute_frequence)
print(frequence("Je suis né dans le béton Coincé entre deux maisons".split()))
```

after the code,
this is the output:

```
premier podium <class 'list'>
deuxieme podium <class 'list'>
troisieme podium <class 'NoneType'>
```

I don't understand why the podium variable loses his type.

Someone said me:

"Now, i think your problem is this: troisieme podium  - right? It's because of podium = podium.append(frequence). Just append the new value to your list, re-assigning the variable istn't correct here. Just do podium.append(frequence)".

It's right. but I don't understand why. possibly we consider this as a new variable. And what can I do if I need to make e.g. something with a method that do not alter the named variable until writing variable = variable.method() {in ruby language there is method with "!" and without '!"}

Comment: Python variables don't have types on their own, instead they are bound to objects and it's the *underlying object* that has a type.  Initially you have `podium` bound to a list, then you re-bind it to an object of type `NoneType` (more precisely, *the* object, it's a singleton).

Comment: The problem is `podium.append(frequence)` returns `None`, so when you do `podium = podium.append(frequence)` it changes the value of `podium` to that after appending the value to the list. The simplest thing to do would be to just remove the assignment part. You could also change it to the equivalent `podium += [frequence]`.

Comment: @martineau Thank so much! If in my power, I wish someone explain me how is it possible that a list is non type object. first, I know that list.append(item) is the same list that contain a new item. What is the rational of this rule? it's very unexpected for the simple beginner.

Comment: `podium` is the name of an object which is an instance of the `list` class. `podium.append` is the name of a function — also known as a method — which adds an element to the end of _that_ list. All functions return something, which is the value `None` by default. _By convention_, the methods of all of Python's built-in container classes do not return the modified object as their result — so instead they return the default value `None`. Your code takes this very inconvenient & worthless return value and assigns it to the name of the list, thereby losing track of the list object itself.

Comment: @martineau. Very beautiful explanation, that reflect the bone structure of the language. If you permitt, I want to ask a complement of the question: the .split() method folow a different rule, is it linked with the will to spare the original object when the action modify it's type (as str to list)? Very interesting

Comment: [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) doesn't modify the string in-place — it can't because strings are immutable in Python — so it _does_ return a value, but that value is not a string. The value returned is a list of string elements that were found delimited by whitespace (the default) or an optional `sep=` keyword argument. So given a string consisting of space-separated words, it will return them all as elements of a list.

Comment: @martineau. good! now I know that the default output of the function, in other words, the function of nothing, is "None". I  undrestand that when you pointed "return value" you don't mind the end od the function "return()"?  but that it is better to write mylist.append simply, or max(list) in a new line and finally ...  return(max(podium)). It's very clean practice. Thanks,

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not completely sure, but it sounds like you now mostly understanding the way things work.

Comment: I you are not completely sure, you're right! (:

Comment: @martineau Hi, a last question! E. g the replace method in strings left the str as it was. If I want to run a succession of steps, it sames that the only one solution is to write str = str.replace('x', 'y'). Is it in python an equivalent of the "!" in ruby? (I believe that the question is legitimate (?) ... )

Comment: Yes, it's possible to chain several operations together as long as you assign the final result to something. i.e. `s = s.strip().lower().replace('x', 'y')` would replace the initial value of `s` with the one returned from the last step. You could answer questions like this yourself by just trying it and seeing what happens. The Python interactive shell is a great tool for such experimentation.

Comment: @martineau Hi the replace method in strings left the str as it was. To modify it we write str = str.replace('x', 'y'), str.replace('x', 'y') is a name of a new string. If I do a similar manipulation with a list by the .append method. this transform the list. list.append('x') is not the name of a new list, it describe an action on the list. If I write list = list.append('x'), the list is reinitialized to the name of the action. list = list.append('x') is to banish. nevertheless, It seems as a lack of consistency of the language that left to coexist two species of methods. What is the rational?

Comment: It's consistent with respect to the fact that lists are mutable and strings aren't. For the built-in types, what a method returns is uniformly governed by the mutability of the type of object to which it applies. You just need to become familiar with the properties of the built-in types, which will happen naturally after you've used them for a while. User-defined types, however, may or may not follow the same rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `append()` method modifies the list in place. It doesn't return a new list, but modifies the list given as parameter. Its return value is None, and that is why your 'troisieme podium' type is NoneType.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a.append(4)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print(a.append(5))
None
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

So this line:

```
podium = podium.append(frequence)
```

should be simply:

```
podium.append(frequence)
```

Comment: If I understand, "list.append(item)" is the name of an action (a function in programing language) the input and the output of this action is considered as the same object as if a man go the taylor, we prefer to consider that the man that entered is the same as the man that exit. It is purely converntional but there is a practicity because the type of variabie remain the same. but if I write int('6') the type were changed and the object is realy of a new nature and int('6' ) is more that an action, that is an acted object genealogically bounded to '6'. Right?

Comment: Not exactly. `l.append(item)` means that you execute the action `append` from the list `l`, with the parameter `item`.
As for functions, parameters are passed by *reference* in Python. This means that in `apply_modification(my_list)`, you don't give the list as a parameter, but the address of the list. Basically, you say "please, apply your modification to the list located here". More on that [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm), they explain better than me.

Answer (score 2):

Because `append` always returns None. You can easily verify this for yourself in the terminal.

There is no append that does not modify in place: the best you can do is copy the list and append to the copy.

Comment: There's no reason not to modify the local variable in place.